# Adding SonicWall VPN connection to Network tab in Settings

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've successfully added a VPN connection via SonicWall NetExtender, but I am annoyed that I can't add it directly to the VPN section within Settings. SonicWall is not compatible with OpenVPN, and I don't see a way to use it in PPTP.

Is there someway around this? I much prefer having all my VPNs in one place, and this is bothering me.

Any advice would be great. I've attached a a link to a screenshot showing my delimma. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Yes it does. But I was under the impression that wouldn't work for SonicWall

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my answer, as I really don't have a good answer for you.

Comment: I am on the same boat and would like a better solution than netextender. the app is just so much hassle